# Redirect php page to another php page using 301 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have a dynamic page that I need to redirect to another dynamic page in .htaccess.

I have tried different syntax for the redirect but nothing seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule /index.php?p=page&page_id=store$ http://www.website.com/index.php [R=301]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=page&page_id=store$
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://www.website.com/index.php? [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:  I have an old php page in the shopping cart that I have transferred to the new address. So in order to preserve search engine page ranking I want to redirect old page to the new address. I want visitors who still visit www.website.com/index.php?p=page&page_id=store to be redirected to website.com/index.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is not working? do you want to append the query string to the rewritten url?

Comment: could you say in words what is the (full) url you are trying to redirect and where so we can compare with the rules you wrote?

Comment: oh just realized comparing to one of my rules, you don't need the / try with just `RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.website.com/index.php? [L,R=301]`, inspired by this rule `RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: xception, I have an old php page in the shopping cart that I have transferred to the new address. So in order to preserve search engine page ranking I want to redirect told page to the new address. I want visitor who still visit www.website.com/index.php?p=page&page_id=store to be redirected to http://www.website.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

URI's that are fed to rewrite rules inside htaccess files always have the leading slash stripped off. So instead of `/index.php`, you have `index.php`, since htaccess files are essentially a per-directory case, similar to the `<Directory>` directive. So you want the second option but without the leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=page&page_id=store$
# no slash --v
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.website.com/index.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. But that didn't work either. I am running pages on Pinnacle Cart, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with specifics of the system.

Comment: @Lenz I don't know anything about the system you are using, but if you want to redirect `/index.php?p=page&page_id=store` to `/index.php`, that's the rule you'd use. If after the redirect, it's still not working, obviously the redirect isn't the problem. Could this be [an XY problem here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Jon, not really. That's all I really need to do, redirect one page to another. Maybe you can suggest more efficient way to do it without using .htaccess redirects?

Comment: @Lenz Those rules do exactly that, as you can see: [in a blank htaccess file in the document root of a new installation of apache](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnxS.png), it does exactly what you're asking. There is something else wrong. For example, maybe you've got `AllowOverride None` when you really want `AllowOverride All` in your server setup, which makes it ignore all htaccess files. This is why I suspect this being an "XY" problem, Y has been solved, but X still persists. Something else is wrong here, and it isn't Y.