# I want to redirect old url to new rewrite url using htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a problem since i using rewrite url..

MY OLD URL:
`Website.com/index.php?act=appdetail&appid=oWV`

New Rewrite URL
`http://website.com/angry_birds_rio-appdetail-oWVi.html`

But all my old url are indexed in google and if any one come to my website its display the old URL and google also INDEXED the NEW URL. its make duplicate page on website problem.

Let me know the solution

My rewrite URL htaccess

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*).html$ index.php?appanme=$1&act=$2&appid=$3&page=$4&cat=$5 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*).html$ index.php?appanme=$1&act=$2&appid=$3&page=$4&cat=$5&sString=$5 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*).html$ index.php?appanme=$1&act=$2&appid=$3[L]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460515/redirect-php-page-to-another-php-page-using-301-htaccess

Comment: its not helping me .. I need a solution.. i am not good htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Here is your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php?act=appdetail&appid=oWV$ http://website.com/angry_birds_rio-appdetail-oWVi.html [R=301,L]
```

You'll need to inform to web crawlers about the redirection, you cando it with a 301 code.

Answer (score 0):

Appears the rule are .htaccess based; you need an additional set of rules to permanently redirect (301) BROWSER/CRAWLER requests for the index.php pages, if a set of CGI arguments are present, to the appropriate alias, this will tidy up Google in a few weeks. Then your rules above e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Permanently redirect BROWSER requests for the index.php?xxx to the appropriate page alias:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /index.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^appanme=([^&]+)&act=([^&]+)&appid=([^&]+)&page=([^&]+)&cat=([^&]+)&sString=([^&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1-%2-%3-%4-%5-%6.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /index.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^appanme=([^&]+)&act=([^&]+)&appid=([^&]+)&page=([^&]+)&cat=([^&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1-%2-%3-%4-%5.html   [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /index.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^appanme=([^&]+)&act=([^&]+)&appid=([^&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1-%2-%3.html   [R=301,L]

# Followed by: YOUR RULES FROM ABOVE
```

**Note**:

1) There appears to be a typo in YOUR second rule: sString=$6  NOT sString=$5

2) The Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation is worth a read if your unclear as to what the above rules do, or if you want something a little more abstract consider the following [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_4043.html).